# split dataframe in r into characters and numbers

Tags: r

is there a way to split dataframe into numbers and alphabets.
For example:I have column that contains values of the following format:

```
Hamiltion xyx 1324-1562 abc
```

I want to take data before the numbers into separate column and the numbers into different column.
I tried using gsub() and sub() but they return empty.
please help!

Comment: Would help to provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: Please provide an example of a small dataframe, and the desired output

Comment: Hi sanjana brid, are you having another user account? http://stackoverflow.com/users/7631583 If so, you might want to merge the two - see [this help center page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a some solutions.  We assume the test data.frame in the Note below was used as input.

**1)**  Use `read.table` to split the whitespace-separate fields and then `read.table` again but this time with `sep = "-"` to split the third column.

```
DF2 <- read.table(text = as.character(DF$x), as.is = TRUE)
cbind(DF2[-3], read.table(text = DF2$V3, sep = "-", col.names = c("A", "B")))
```

giving:

```
         V1  V2  V4    A    B
1 Hamiltion xyx abc 1324 1562
2 Hamiltion xyx abc 1324 1562
3 Hamiltion xyx abc 1324 1562
```

In the test data.frame shown column `x` was a factor but if it were a character column then the `as.character` could have been omitted although it won't hurt if you leave it in.

**2)** If the pattern digit-digit only appears in column 3 then this alternative could work:

```
read.table(text = sub("(\\d)-(\\d)", "\\1 \\2", DF$x), as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
         V1  V2   V3   V4  V5
1 Hamiltion xyx 1324 1562 abc
2 Hamiltion xyx 1324 1562 abc
3 Hamiltion xyx 1324 1562 abc
```

**3)** Another possibility is to use this pattern giving the same result as in (2)

```
pat <- "^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\d+)-(\\d+) (\\S+)$"
read.table(text = sub(pat, "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5", DF$x), as.is = TRUE)
```

**4)** This can be done even more compactly using the same pattern as in (3) with `read.pattern` from the gsubfn package:

```
library(gsubfn)

read.pattern(text = as.character(DF$x), pattern = pat)
```

**Note:**

```
# test data.frame
DF <- data.frame(x = rep("Hamiltion xyx 1324-1562 abc", 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `separate` function from the `tidyr` package could be useful.

```
# Load package
library(tidyr)

# Create example data frame
dat <- data.frame(Col = "Hamiltion xyx 1324-1562 abc", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Separate the columns into new columns
dat %>%
  separate(Col, into = c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"), sep = " ")

#        Col1 Col2      Col3 Col4
# 1 Hamiltion  xyx 1324-1562  abc
```